# Why do I keep getting the Client/Certificate error in python, discord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, certificate, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot in python. I did install the module and upgrade certifi, but i still gat the following error:

```
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')]
```

This is my code:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
client.run(token)
```

Not gonna show my token but u know what I mean.
Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you using python 3.6 on a Mac?

Comment: I'm using python 3.8. Import discord doesn't give me a module error tho.

Comment: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/423 Thought this might have been your problem but it shouldn't be then.

Comment: I've read that already.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Creating a virtual enviroment in Anaconda and adding it as an interpreter in Pycharm solved the problem! Thanks!